# Speeding up a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, indexing

The query uses cakephp to make the call to the database, here is the query:

```
find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(          
    'OR' => array(
        'PdfFolder.is_global' => true,
        'PdfFoldersUser.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
    ),
    'recursive' => 0,
    'order' => array('PdfFolder.is_global DESC', 'PdfFolder.name')
```

The pdffolder table has about 2100 however the relationship table that contains pdf_folder_id and user_id contains nearly 30000 records.  This query at times will take up to 35 seconds to run at certain times.  I did not set up the code, and I am not database expert, this just got dropped on me as a developer.

It looks like id for each table is set up as a primary key, how that is all the indexes that I see.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT**

Table Structure

**users**

```
| id (index) | role_id | username | password | email |
```

**pdf_folders**

```
| id (index) | name | date_created | is_global(bool) |
```

**pdf_folders_users**

```
| id (index) | folder_id | user_id (now an index) |
```

**pdfs**

```
| id (index) | parent_id | pdf_folder_id | ...more file information
```

Comment: What indexes are on that table?

Comment: Just the id of each table set as primary

Answer (score 3):

Start by adding an index on user_id field -

```
CREATE INDEX FK_user_id ON PdfFoldersUser (user_id)
```

It would help if you posted the full table structure for each of the relevant tables.

Comment: Did adding the user_id index improve performance?  What is the actual SQL being executed?

Comment: Did not seem to work. How would I go about getting the actual SQL in cakephp?

Answer (score 1):

@patcouch22

to see your sql in the view

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

to see it in the controller

```
$this->render('sql');
```